# gnuplot: plotting three lines points problems

Tags: gnuplot

```
set title "Time Intervals"
set ylabel 'Y axis'
set xlabel 'Time'
set output 'output.eps'
set terminal postscript eps enhanced color font 'Helvetica-Bold'
set key noinvert samplen 4 spacing 1.5 width 3 height 1
set key width 6.8 height 0.5 box top right
set xrange[0:11]
set yrange [0:1]
set xtics 1
set ytics 0.1
set xlabel font "Arial-Bold,20"
set ylabel font "Arial-Bold,20"
set xtics font "Arial-Bold,20"
set ytics font "Arial-Bold,20"
set key font "Arial-Bold,20"
set title font "Arial-Bold,20"
plot  "data" using 1:2  title  "t1" with linespoint lw 5.5 pt 6 ps 3.5 lt 1 lc rgb "blue" ,\
      "data" using 1:3  title  "t2" with linespoint lw 9.5 pt 3 ps 2.5 lt 1 lc rgb "red" ,\
      "data" using 1:4  title   "t3" with linespoint lw 9.5 pt 8 ps 2.5 lt 1 lc rgb "green"
```

DataFile

```
0    0       -99      -99
1    0       -99      -99
2    0       -99      -99
3    0       0.2      -99
4    -99     0.25     -99
5    -99     0.3      -99
6    -99     0.35     -99
7    -99     0.5      -99
8    -99      0.5       0
9    -99     -99        0
10    -99     -99        0
11    -99     -99        0
```

[image]

Please anyone help. After running this code I have  face one problem. t2 should  start from time=3 and it should connect with t1 when time=2. In same way when t3(ends at time 8) and t2 should connect time =9.

Comment: What is the criterion for *not* drawing a point in your data set?   The program has correctly drawn all points for which y != -99.   How is it supposed to figure out that you do not want a t1 point at (x=3 y=0)?

Comment: Question answered? If yes, please accept the answer. If no, please specify what is missing.

Answer (score 1):

As Ethan mentioned in the comments, what is the condition for plotting and connecting?
From your description I assume that you might want to plot and connect the maxima of columns 2, 3 and 4 with the corresponding linewidths, pointtypes, pointsizes, and colors.

Since you are plotting 3 different curves they will *not* be connected. In case they need to be connected: What should be the color and linewidth for the connections?

Although, you could plot the data as one curve with variable pt, ps, and color. However, there is no variable linewidth. Furthermore, you would have to create the 3 key entries manually (*edit: see alternative solution below*).

Anyway, in the simplified example below, 3 functions are defined using the ternary operator (check `help ternary`)

- `colMax()` returns the number of the 3 columns which holds the maximum value
- `isMax()` returns the value of the column (first input parameter) if the value is larger than the values of the other columns (2nd, 3rd input parameter) and `NaN` otherwise (i.e. not plotted).
- `color()` returns the color as RGB value (scheme: `0xrrggbb`) as function of column number

The connection lines are plotted first with variable color but constant linewidth (since there is no easy variable linewidth).

**Script:**

```
### conditional plot
reset session

$Data <<EOD
0    0       -99      -99
1    0       -99      -99
2    0       -99      -99
3    0       0.2      -99
4    -99     0.25     -99
5    -99     0.3      -99
6    -99     0.35     -99
7    -99     0.5      -99
8    -99      0.5       0
9    -99     -99        0
10    -99     -99        0
11    -99     -99        0
EOD

isMax(col1,col2,col3)  = (v1=column(col1), v2=column(col2), v3=column(col3), \
                          v1>v2 && v1>v3 ? column(col1) : NaN)
colMax(col1,col2,col3) = (v1=column(col1), v2=column(col2), v3=column(col3), \
                         v1>v2 && v1>v3 ? col1 : v2>v1 && v2>v3 ? col2 : col3)
color(col) = int(word("0x0000ff 0xff0000 0x00ff00",col-1))

set xrange[0:11]
set yrange[0:1]
set key spacing 2.0

plot $Data u 1:(column(colMax(2,3,4))):(color(colMax(2,3,4))) w l lw 5.5 lc rgb var notitle, \
        '' u 1:(isMax(2,3,4)) w lp lw 5.5 pt 6 ps 3.5 lc "blue"  ti "t1", \
        '' u 1:(isMax(3,2,4)) w lp lw 9.5 pt 3 ps 2.5 lc "red"   ti "t2", \
        '' u 1:(isMax(4,2,3)) w lp lw 9.5 pt 8 ps 2.5 lc "green" ti "t3"
### end of script
```

**Result:** (wxt terminal)

[image]

**Alternative Solution:** (with fixed linewidth and variable ps,pt,color)

Attention: there is/was a mix-up of order of variable pointtype and pointsize from gnuplot 5.2 to 5.4 (see https://sourceforge.net/p/gnuplot/bugs/2524/). Depending on your version you might need to adapt the order.

**Script:** (tested with gnuplot 5.2.8)

```
### conditional plot
reset session

$Data <<EOD
0    0       -99      -99
1    0       -99      -99
2    0       -99      -99
3    0       0.2      -99
4    -99     0.25     -99
5    -99     0.3      -99
6    -99     0.35     -99
7    -99     0.5      -99
8    -99      0.5       0
9    -99     -99        0
10    -99     -99        0
11    -99     -99        0
EOD

colMax(col1,col2,col3) = (v1=column(col1), v2=column(col2), v3=column(col3), \
                         v1>v2 && v1>v3 ? col1 : v2>v1 && v2>v3 ? col2 : col3)

myColors     = "0x0000ff 0xff0000 0x00ff00"
myColor(col) = int(word(myColors,col-1))
myPts        = "6 3 8"
myPt(col)    = int(word(myPts,col-1))
myPss        = "3.5 2.5 2.5"
myPs(col)    = real(word(myPss,col-1))
myTitles     = "t1 t2 t3"
myTitle(col) = word(myTitles,col-1)

set xrange[0:11]
set yrange[0:1]
set key spacing 2.0

plot $Data u 1:(c=colMax(2,3,4),column(c)):(myPs(c)):(myPt(c)):(myColor(c)) w lp \
        ps var pt var lc rgb var lw 5.5 notitle, \
     for [c=2:4] keyentry w lp ps myPs(c) pt myPt(c) lc rgb myColor(c) lw 5.5 ti myTitle(c)
### end of script
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: First of all thanks alot for your answer.This will solve my problem. The above figure is what i want. But i have a query. I want to have two files Data.txt file where i will store the data entries only and gnuplot file Time.p where i want to write the above script. Then through the terminal i will run as  gnuplot "Time.p" and want to get the result in output file in eps file. I try to run in this way but i got a error..Please help!!!!

Comment: @Wang I am not sure I understand your problem. In the example above the data is already included in the script. If you have a separate datafile: remove the `$Data <<EOD ... EOD` section and in the plot command replace `$Data` with `'Data.txt'`. Was this your question?

Comment: i put your above code in one file and name it (Time.p) and run to run with command in terminal as ( gnuplot "Time.p"). This is the error i got

Comment: $Data <<EOD
^
"Time.p", line 3: invalid command

Comment: @Wang which version of gnuplot are you running? Maybe some 4.x version?

Comment: G N U P L O T
Version 4.6 patchlevel 4

Comment: @Wang Ouch, this version is about 9 years old. Can't you update to a newer version? As I said above remove the `$Data <<EOD ... EOD` section etc. and this error should disappear.

Comment: thank you..let me update ...

Comment: Thank you once again...now its ok...

Comment: @Wang if the answer solved your problem, please select the check mark and/or upvote button next to the answer indicating that your question is answered.

Comment: @theozh Helpful efforts, communication and structure. Do we consider this as a x,y,z plot or a multicolumn plot?

Comment: @bonCodigo this just a 2D-plot using x and y (no "3D" `splot` using x,y,z). I don't know, you could call it a "conditional multicolumn plot".